# Grails The requested resource (/Receipts/receipts/index) is not available

Tags: grails, controller, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I have been attempting to learn Grails, however I am running into the following problem.  I have created four domain classes (Receipts, Items, Categories, and Owners), and I created four controllers for each domain class (ReceiptsController, ItemsController, CategoriesController, and OwnersController). The domains and the controllers are each in com.receipts packages.

In each controller, I have only the following:

```
package com.receipts

class ReceiptsController {

     static scaffolding = Receipts

}
```

However, when I start the server (localhost:8080) I receive the following error, for each of the four controllers:

```
"The requested resource (/Receipts/receipts/index) is not available"
```

Does anyone know what is going on here? I also tried the following formats for the scaffolding:

- static scaffolding = true
- def scaffolding = Receipts
- def scaffolding = true

...and those don't work, either. I also tried generating the views for the Receipts domain class, but that didn't do anything either. Neither does cleaning the project.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right code is

```
static scaffold = true
```